# javascript,html dont check ssl certificate or bypass error

Tags: javascript, html, ssl

Good afternoon,
in my html there is a code like < script src=https://example.com/script.js >,
but the problem is that example.com does not have a valid certificate and it only works on port 443.
Is it possible to load a script without checking ssl?

Comment: `https://example.com` isn't a script, it's a webpage. What is it you're trying to do?  Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to override browser certificate verification using HTML or Javascript.  That would be a huge security risk and almost make it meaningless for security.

If you want it to work you will have to trust the certificate, or one in the chain of trust, on each client computer that accesses your page.